# Is it possible to do a test of significance for a string occurrence in two datasets in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, statistics, dataset, find-occurrences

I have two sets of data both compiled from different sources. Both set of data contains word with a frequency of occurrence. I would like to check if a certain word exists in both dataset and if they do, is it possible to perform some kind of test of significance statistically to prove the word is significant.

```
For example:

word = 'apple'
dict1 = {'oranges': 45, 'apple': 34,...., 'x': y}
dict2 = {'apple': 165, 'orange': 12,...., 'x': y}
```

If the word 'apple' appears in both dataset (dict1 and dict2), then calculate test of significance for the word apple.

Comment: i think this is more of a statistics question than a programming question, try posting on crossvalidated

Comment: @qwwqwwq The first part of the question could be answered here though

Comment: The words in both datasets are `[k for k in dict1 if k in dict2]`. I can't help you with the statistics though.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the words that occur in both sources is easy enough:

```
(set(dict1) & set(dict2))
```

Passing the dict to `set` creates a set of the dictionary's keys, then `&` is the set intersection operator.

The simplest test we can possibly do for statistical significance is a chisquare test, using a dummy variable to compare "one vs all" counts for each word in common. You can use the implementation in `scipy`. Putting it all together you could do something like this:

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare
import numpy as np

dict1 = { 'cat': 20, 'dog': 40 }
dict2 = { 'cat': 22, 'dog': 38 }

def get_freqs_for_chisq(dict1, dict2):
    for key in (set(dict1) & set(dict2)):
        yield key
        for d in [dict1, dict2]:
            other_freq = sum([v for (k,v) in d.iteritems() if k != key])
            freq = d[key]
            yield np.array([freq, other_freq])

iter = get_freqs_for_chisq(dict1, dict2)
results = {}
while True:
    try:
        word = iter.next()
        results[word] = dict(zip(('chisq', 'P'),
                                chisquare(iter.next(), f_exp=iter.next())))
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Which would give you output like this:

```
{'cat': {'P': 0.59209697588539778, 'chisq': 0.28708133971291866},
 'dog': {'P': 0.59209697588539778, 'chisq': 0.28708133971291866}}
```